# Mapping Spring Beans To Integer Identifiers

Tags: java, spring

My application uses a set of **command classes with unique integer identifiers** to execute different tasks. Commands are stored in an **enum** class of form

```
public enum CommandType {

    COMMAND1(1000, Command1.class),
    COMMAND2(1001, Command2.class),
    ...
```

In the legacy code, we were constructing the corresponding command instance using the command id when a request is received. Recently I added Spring support and now each command is marked with `@Controller` annotation. Instead of constructing a new instance, now we do

```
Class<? extends Command> commandClass = commandType.getCommandClass();    
applicationContext.getBean(commandClass);
```

Command ids are stored in a **hashmap** and we obtain the corresponding commands from this map

```
private Map<Integer, CommandType> commandTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

What I wonder is instead of using a hashmap, can I utilize Spring. Is there an easy and graceful way to map the command beans into unique command ids in the Spring Framework, so that I can acquire the command by passing the id into Spring?

Comment: Qualifier annotation is used to define custom names for your beans. While I can technically give command ids as qualifiers, that's not really what I am looking for here. I just want to know if Spring has a similar sort of mapping technique to objects of similar purposes, like enumarations.

Comment: And that should only return command beans, not the other beans in my system.

Answer (score 0):

**@Controller** annotation can have as parameter the bean name

Example :

```
@Controller("1000") 
public class COMMAND1{
}
```

and then you can get instance of this bean by using his name

```
Command1 cmd1=(Command1) applicationContext.getBean("1000");
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. But like I said in the comments, I am looking for a mapper kind of feature, not passing an integer to the bean qualifier.